# Load more records (Listview) on reaching list end

Tags: android, node.js, mongodb, pagination, mongoose-plugins

I have requirement where in my listview should display the next 10 values by reading from the server when a user reaches the end of the list on the screen scroll.

I am using "volley" to get the data from the server asynchronously. My server code is built on Node.js + mongoose within it and MongoDB. 
I have read about Mongoose pagination on at [npm-mongoose-paginate](https://www.npmjs.org/package/mongoose-paginate). Can someone help me/ explain me with a clear example in using this. Thank you

Comment: mongoose has nothing to do with listview pagination. there should be a webservice to call if you list ends and request more 10 records like http://example.com/1.. http://example.com/2, when you receive your data on android side update your model and notify listview to updateitself